# Continuous functions $f$ satisfying $\int_{0}^{x^2} f(x) = 1-e^{2x^2}$

Tags: calculus

> Find all continuous functions $f$ satisfying $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x^2} f(t)dt = 1-e^{2x^2}$.

I differentiated both sides to get $2xf(x^2) = -4e^{2x^2}x$, so I concluded that

$$f(x) =\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
  &-2e^{2x}, \qquad x>0 \cr 
  &\text{any continuous function on $(-\infty,0]$ containing the point.} 
  \end{aligned}\right.$$

Comment: There is an error of differentiation, on the left use the chain rule.

Comment: Note that $\int_0^{x^2}f(x)$ doesn't quite make sense. I understand what you're after, but the correct way of writing it would be $\int_0^{x^2}f(s)\,ds$ (or use any other symbol in place of $s$, except $x$).

Comment: @Arthur Is my answer right now?

Comment: what does it mean that a continuous function over some range *contains a point*?

Comment: That's better. One problem right now is that you have a missing $-$ in your final answer.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm not sure what you are asking. How is my answer wrong?

Comment: @Arthur Is my answer correct now?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be simplified to say that, for $x\ge0$,
$$
\int_0^xf(t)\,dt=1-e^{2x}
$$
that gives you $f(x)=-2e^{2x}$.

You should say more about $f$ on the interval $(-\infty,0)$: it is an arbitrary continuous function over this interval, but satisfying
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=-2
$$
in order to ensure continuity also at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{x^2} f(x) =[F(x)]_{0}^{x^2}= 1-e^{2x^2}$$ Take $$F(x)=-e^{2x}+g(x)$$ so you have $$F(x^2)=-e^{2x^2}+g(x^2)\\F(0)=-1+g(0)\\F(x^2)-F(0)=-e^{-2x^2}+1+(g(x^2)-g(0)$$ We can do $g(x)=0$ so $F(x)=-e^{2x}$ and $$f(x)=F'(x)=\color{red}{-2e^{2x}}$$